# Looking for Postgres query which can provide output like MongoDB group by function

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

**Product table**

```
|_id|name  |
|---|------|
|3  |Laptop|
```

**Size table**

```
|_id|product_id|size|
|---|----------|----|
|5  |3         |15  |
|6  |3         |17  |
```

**Query:**

```
select tp._id, tp.name, ts.size from test_product tp 
  left join test_size ts on tp._id = ts.product_id 
  group by tp._id, tp.name, ts.size
where tp._id = 3 limit 10 offset 0
```

**Current output:**

```
|_id|name  |size|
|---|------|----|
|3  |Laptop|15  |
|3  |Laptop|17  |
```

**Expected output**

```
|_id|name  |size   |
|---|------|-------|
|3  |Laptop|[15,17]|
```

**Note:**
Due to current query I'm getting 2 record for the same product and my limit and offset query logic is getting false and not getting proper count. I'm not well aware of **Postgres** queries for this kind of situation. So I need solution for this so my limit and offset logic will be correct for fetching data and for this query my count of product will be 1.

Comment: You mean array_agg() ? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)():

```
SELECT
    tp._id,
    tp.name,
    ARRAY_AGG(ts.size ORDER BY ts.size) -- ORDER BY to get consistent results
FROM
    test_product tp
    LEFT JOIN test_size ts ON tp._id = ts.product_id 
GROUP BY
    tp._id,
    tp.name 
WHERE
    tp._id = 3 
LIMIT 10 
OFFSET 0;
```

The ORDER BY within the aggregation is optional, but it's always nice to get consistent results over and over again.